# Visual Studio 2013 InstallShield Limited - Installing files into MyDocuments

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield-le

I am using Visual Studio 2013, InstallShield Limited.  One of the 'Predefined Folder' options available in InstallShield Limited, is "[MyPicturesFolder]".  I need to be able to install to the user's MyDocuments folder (per company requirements).  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I just noticed [PersonalFolder].  I bet that is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by @JonathanHansen in the comment under the question, the `[PersonalFolder]` is indeed the *My Documents* folder. See: [Personal folders overview](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/personal_folders_overview.mspx?mfr=true)

To set this as an output location, in Visual Studio, under Solution Explorer, navigate to the installer project, then under **2 Specify Application Data** > **Files**, right-click the **Destination Computer** (under Destination computer's files on the left), and select **Show Predefined Folder**. Then, select **[PersonalFolder]**. Any files added here will end up under My Documents.

I tested this on Windows 7. A file that I put there ended up on the destination computer under: C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\

Also see [Destination Folders](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpISXFilesDestinations.htm) for more information.